# Close/dismiss button in apex addmessage

Tags: apex, visualforce, adderror

I'm looking a way to have a close button on the pagemessage after it displays the message or dismiss after few seconds something similar to JQuery.

VFP:

```
<apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
```

APEX:

```
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(
             ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Saved successfully!'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried something similar in the past.

**For click to clear action**

Although I didn't get any close symbol, I was able to capture any click on the `outputPanel` which contained the `pageMessage`, and call an `actionFunction` which would simply reRender the panel. This would clear the messages. 
You could try to inject some symbol or message through JavaScript.

**Timed clearing**

So the important thing here is that on save I make the timer boolean as true. And then rerender the panel that contains the `ActionPoller`. The ActionPoller waits for 10 seconds and then calls the timerOff method and rerenders the `outputPanel` containing the `pageMessage`.

See the relevant VF sections and controller below to achieve the above two scenarios. It uses pure Visualforce and controller logic to achieve this.

**Visualforce**

```
 <apex:outputPanel id="messagePanel" onclick="clearMessage();">
       <apex:pageMessages id="message"></apex:pageMessages>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    .....

    <apex:commandButton value="Save" 
             reRender="pbId,timerPanel" 
             rendered="{!acc.id==editId}" 
             action="{!saveRecord}">    
     .....


    <apex:outputPanel id="timerPanel">
        <apex:actionPoller reRender="messagePanel" 
                  interval="10" 
                  enabled="{!timer}" 
                  action="{!timerOff}"/> 
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:actionFunction name="clearMessage" 
                action="{!timerOff}" 
                reRender="messagePanel"/>
```

**Controller**

```
public class AccountController {

    public List<Account> accountList{get; set;}
    public boolean timer {get; set;}

    public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        accountList = [select id,name,billingcity,Phone,Website from Account limit 20];
    }

    public void saveRecord(){
        update accountList;
        editId = null;
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(
             ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Saved successfully!'));

        timerOn();
    }

    public void clearMessage(){
        ApexPages.getMessages().clear();

    }

    public void timerOn(){
        timer = true;
    }

    public void timerOff(){
        timer = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: the timer is not firing and the message still displays and i have waited few mnts to see

Comment: Well it should work. Make sure your rerender is specifying the right panel.

Comment: `pbId` what is that? or is it suppose to be `message`

Comment: Yeah you may need to check if all the ids are correct. I just took parts of some code I had written and put it here. Pbid was the id of some other page block.

Answer (score 0):

What if:

1. you had a method in your class say:

   ```
   public void doNothing(){}
   ```
2. then your command button executes that method and you have a rerender on the button to rerender the messages

You may need an actionregion around the button depending on the error...

**CLASS**

```
public with sharing class myTestController {



    public void throwError(){
        apexPages.addMessage(New ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'A message'));
    }

    public void donothing(){}



}
```

**VF PAGE**

```
<apex:page controller="mytestcontroller" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">


    <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!throwError}" value="Make Error" rerender="msgs"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!donothing}" value="Clear Error" rerender="msgs"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you trying to say

Comment: A method and a button with rerender, should remove your message after you click it. Not sure how to put it any simpler

Comment: so if the user click on `Save` button it gets a message saying that `record is saved successfully` then which button to remove the message? the same `Save` button ? if you rerender the button the it will never show the message?

Comment: Um, no, you add a "close message button" thats what you asked for. "way to have a close button on the pagemessage "

Comment: do you have similar sample code to demonostrate

Comment: It is already there. Sorry, but there is nothing more I can do to help you. The code is ALL there. just create the button.

Comment: maybe posting it as a working example will help.

Comment: i was thinking that you can add `commandButton or Hyperlink inside the pageMessages` but it seems like you need to have a commandButton separately to clear the message.

Comment: You could add a HTML button to your message and have it call an action function that does the same thing. but it will only work for messages you add